# how to mention withkeepBinary in %ignite.ignitesql interpreter in zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin, ignite

I saved some Spark dataset in IgniteRDD with key and Value both as BinaryObject and it works fine also I am able to query in back using Ignite code with %ignite interpreter sample below.

```
%ignite
import org.apache.ignite._
import org.apache.ignite.binary._
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query._
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val cache: IgniteCache[BinaryObject, BinaryObject] = ignite.cache("test123")

val qry = new SqlFieldsQuery(
"select _val from testValue", 
true)
val res = cache.withKeepBinary().query(qry).getAll()

collectionAsScalaIterable(res).foreach(println _)
```

But when I try to query same with %ignite.ignitesql interpreter

```
%ignite.ignitesql 
select * from testValue
```

it fails with "Failed resolve class for ID: -1422444403"

To me it seems difference in both way is that in First I specified withKeepBinary() , how similar can be done in %ignite.ignitesql so that  can use sql directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible now, I created a ticket to fix this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4141

But in any case, I would recommend to avoid `select *` queries when working with Ignite, because the result set will include predefined `_key` and `_val` fields that represent full object. It's better to explicitly list the fields that you need in the result set so that you do not fetch the data you don't need.